used kafka in unty, but force quit
I can't speak English. Sorry in advance.
i used kafka consume in uniyt. and i want safe shutdown kafka. so i used Close() or Dispose() in OnApplicationQuit(), but unity not work and force quit.
using Confluent.Kafka;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;

public class _KafkaConsume : MonoBehaviour
{
    private IConsumer<Ignore, string> _consumer;
    private const string _topic = "testTopic";
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;

    private async void Start()
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var config = new ConsumerConfig
        {
            BootstrapServers = "ip",
            AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Latest,
            GroupId = "consumerGroup",
            BrokerAddressFamily = BrokerAddressFamily.V4,
            EnableAutoCommit = false,
        };

        _consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(config).Build();
        _consumer.Subscribe(_topic);

        await Task.Run(() => ConsumeMessagesAsync(_cancellationTokenSource.Token));
    }

    private async Task ConsumeMessagesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                var consumeResult = _consumer.Consume(cancellationToken);
                if (consumeResult != null && consumeResult.Message != null)
                {
                    Debug.Log($"Received message: {consumeResult.Message.Value}");
                }
            }
            catch (ConsumeException e)
            {
                Debug.LogError($"Error consuming message: {e.Error}");
            }
        }
    }
    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        if (_consumer != null)
        {
            _consumer.Close(); // problematic part!!!!!!
        }
    }

}

just play game, and end game. then force quit for unity.
ask Chat GPT, he said : in code "problematic part" is absolutely necessary.
if delete that, my unity is work and not quit.
sorry my english is weird but someone help me. .. ..

I think you need to drop the Task.Run() and keep a variable so you can cancel the task, its the not cancelling the task that is causing it IMHO
